# How to execute bound function outside of event handler in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm probably asking the wrong question, but I'd like to be able to execute a parent function when called from a child function, not an event.

I have more or the less the following setup: Declaring the _foo method in the parent and passing it on down to ChildTwo, where executing it via an onClick event handler works as expected. However, I ran into a situation where I need to call the _foo method manually from inside another method (I've simplified it here, but it will be called conditionally).

My question is what do I need to do to call the _foo method from _bar() ?

Thanks in advance!

```js
export defaultclass Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  _foo() {
    alert('alert!');
  }

  render() { <ChildOne _foo={this._foo.bind(this)} /> }
}

const ChildOne = (props) => {
  const { _foo } = props;
  return ( <ChildTwo _foo={_foo} /> );
}

export default class ChildTwo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._foo = this.props._foo.bind(this);
  }

  _bar() {
    //this._foo.call();
    //this._foo();
    //what do I do here?
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this._foo}> Works! </button>
          <button onClick={this._bar}>Doesnt Work!</button>
        </div>
      );
  }
};
```

Comment: This shouldn't work: `<button onClick={this._foo}> Works! </button>` or at least shouldn't really do anything, since `this._foo` is undefined. I'm assuming it's just a typo in the example, so could you perhaps check your snippet again, to see if it matches your original code, and fix any typos?

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen ah yes, thank you! 'Tis fixed.

Comment: When using a function within a component as a callback, you have to bind the callback function to the component, otherwise using `this` in the function body would reference the wrong object. So in your `ChildTwo`-component, you should add this line to your constructor: `this._bar = this._bar.bind(this)`. Then you can go ahead and call `this._foo();` in the body of `_bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this, then I would solve it by passing the child component as an argument to the method that is still bound to the original parent.

For example:

```
export defaultclass Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._foo = this._foo.bind(this)
  }

  _foo(childComponent) {
    alert({ parent: this, child: childComponent });
  }

  render() { <ChildOne _foo={this._foo} /> }
}

const ChildOne = (props) => {
  const { _foo } = props;
  return ( <ChildTwo _foo={_foo} /> );
}

export default class ChildTwo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._bar = this._bar.bind(this);
  }

  _bar() {
    const { _foo } = this.props;

    // Passing a reference to self as argument
    _foo(this);
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this._bar}>Should Work Now!</button>
        </div>
      );
  }
};
```